# Close of menu and icon image when click on another menu?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

When click on Hamburg menu, the search menu should be closed and its icon should be of search not the cross and when clicking on search menu, the hamburg menu should be closed and icon convert to hamburg not remain cross.'

```
// Mobile/tablet navigation (clicks, taps)              
$('.toggle-sm-nav, .js-toggle-sm-navigation').click(function(){

                    // Change button
                    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify icon-close-menu-cross2');

                    // Toggle menu on hamburger
                    $('.navcontainer').toggle();
                    $('.header-nav-container').toggleClass('brgropen');

                    if( $('.header-nav-container').hasClass('brgropen') ){
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                    } else {
                        $('body').css('overflow', 'visible');
                    }
```

Another Menu Search

Focus search field when opened

```
    $('.js-toggle-xs-search').on('click', function(){
        $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').trigger('touchstart');
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code or create scenario in jsfiddle or any of that kind...

Comment: I second that, i don't really understand the question. I'm not sure what the setTimeout function relates to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       if ($('.xs-search > button > span').hasClass('icon-close-menu-cross2')) {
         $('.xs-search > button > span').removeClass('icon-close-menu-cross2').addClass('icon-search');
         $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').hide();
         $('.searchboxc').find('.site-search').removeClass('active');
       }
       $('.navcontainer').toggle();
       $('.header-nav-container').toggleClass('brgropen');
       if ($('.header-nav-container').hasClass('brgropen'))

         $('.js-toggle-xs-search').on('click', function() {
         var width = $(window).width();
         if (width <= 968) {
           if ($('.sm-searchboxc input#search').hide()) {
             $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').show();
           } else if ($('.xs-search > button > span').hasClass('icon-close-menu-cross2')) {
             $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').trigger('touchstart');
           }
           if ($('.header-nav-container').hasClass('brgropen')) {
             $('.toggle-sm-nav, .js-toggle-sm-navigation').children('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-align-justify icon-close-menu-cross2');
             $('.navcontainer').hide();
             $('.header-nav-container').removeClass('brgropen');
           }
         } else {
           $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').trigger('touchstart');
         }
       });
       $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').on('touchstart', function() {
             setTimeout(function() {
                   $('.sm-searchboxc input#search').focus();
```

Comment: Please don't post your complete code as answer. Please edit your original question instead.

Comment: @MERose: it looks like this is the solution to the question, so it *should* be posted as an answer. Without an explanation as to what changed, it is not useful to anyone else however.

Comment: Okay, it looked like this was the reaction to the first comment on the question. But I second, answers without explanation are useless.